# Is it possible to redirect user and set x-forwarded-for with PHP?

Tags: php

So with the following I redirect:

```
  header('Location: http://example.com/testpage.php');
```

I would like the example.com to receive a custom x-forwarded-for: header that is set from this redirect page. How may I do this without fiddling with apache?

Comment: `x-forwarded-for` is usually used when there is a reverse-proxy in front of the web server to obtain the *real* IP address of the client connection. Unless you're acting as a proxy, I advise you not to fiddle with it. And if `example.com` uses a reverse-proxy, it will overwrite your value.

Comment: theres no legit reason to want to do this

Comment: And if there is a proxy, it will usually remove any `x-forwarded-for` headers in the incoming request.

Comment: i think you're probably looking for $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: When you send the `Location` header, you are asking the client (browser) to do the redirect.  It's up to it whether it follows the location or not.  It's also up to the client whether or not it send any headers.  Usually it does not send any referer headers.  As for custom headers, you cannot tell the client what headers to send.